# Failing to download Leiningen standalone jar file

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am simply unable to install leiningen on Debian linux :

```
> lein
Downloading Leiningen to /home/debianaut/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.4.3-standalone.jar now...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   355  100   355    0     0    240      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   375
100 14.2M  100 14.2M    0     0  51565      0  0:04:48  0:04:48 --:--:-- 41059
Failed to download https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.4.3/leiningen-2.4.3-standalone.jar
It's possible your HTTP client's certificate store does not have the
correct certificate authority needed. This is often caused by an
out-of-date version of libssl. Either upgrade it or set HTTP_CLIENT
to turn off certificate checks:
  export HTTP_CLIENT="wget --no-check-certificate -O" # or
  export HTTP_CLIENT="curl --insecure -f -L -o"
It's also possible that you're behind a firewall haven't yet
set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.
```

I tried with setting HTTP_CLIENT but still same error . The version I read from lein script is `2.4.3`.

Comment: Where did you get the lein script?

Comment: I get the link from instruction on page: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen as:=> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein

Comment: Did you try upgrading libssl like the error message says?

Comment: I did `dist-upgrade` but no luck , I am currently at : `Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)`

Comment: What versions of curl and wget do you have?

Comment: `wget --version` =>  `GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on linux-gnu.`
and  `curl -V` =>
`curl 7.26.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3`

Comment: Silly question, but did you first do `apt-get update` before the `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: yes several times :)

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this error. This is what I did in Ubuntu 15.04, with Leiningen 2.5.2.

1. Save the [lein](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein) file into the `~bin` directory (create it if it doesn't exist).
2. Change the permissions of the `lein` file to make it executable  (chmod 755 ~/bin/lein)
3. Open `lein` with a text editor
4. On line 116, change `.jar` to `.zip`, so that it should be `LEIN_JAR="$LEIN_HOME/self-installs/leiningen-$LEIN_VERSION-standalone.zip"`
5. Download Leiningen 2.5.2 from [GitHub](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.5.2/leiningen-2.5.2-standalone.zip).
6. Put the zip file `leiningen-2.5.2-standalone.zip` into `~/.lein/self-installs` (do not unzip - create the directory if it doesn't exist - this is a hidden directory, in Gnome Files, hit `Ctrl+H` to see it)
7. To initiate your first project: `lein new MyFirstLeinProject`

Voilà.

Comment: thanks for details instructions, probably you need to fork the lein script on ghithub :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using leiningen 2.1.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion). That script tried to download https://leiningen.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/leiningen-2.1.3-standalone.jar

Eventually I went back to leiningen.org and fetched the current lein script from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein

It worked well. The resource downloaded was: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.5.1/leiningen-2.5.1-standalone.zip